# XSLT to sequence records within each group

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

We have a requirement to sort the input XML by a specific element and assign a sequence number within each group of records.

In the below sample XML, Is it possible to sort the nodes by Genre and assign a sequence number to the nodes corresponding to a particular Genre? If there are 2 nodes with Genre as 'Fantasy', they need to appear together and a tag should be added to each record displaying the number of that record within each genre.

Thank You!

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="bookGenre" match="Book" use="genre" />

    <xsl:template match="Books">
        <Books>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Book[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('bookGenre',genre)[1])]"/>
        </Books>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Book">

            <xsl:for-each select="key('bookGenre', genre)">
                <Book>
                        <genre><xsl:value-of select="genre" /></genre>
                        <author><xsl:value-of select="author" /></author>
                <title><xsl:value-of select="title" /></title>
                    <price><xsl:value-of select="price" /></price>
                    <groupSeqId><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></groupSeqId>

                </Book>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML:

```
   <Books>
           <Book id="bk101">
              <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
              <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
              <genre>Computer</genre>
              <price>44.95</price>
           </Book>
           <Book id="bk102">
              <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
              <title>Midnight Rain</title>
              <genre>Fantasy</genre>
              <price>$5.95</price>
           </Book>
           <Book id="bk103">
              <author>Corets, Eva</author>
              <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
              <genre>Fiction</genre>
              <price>5.95</price>
           </Book>
           <Book id="bk104">
              <author>Corets, Eva</author>
              <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
              <genre>Fantasy</genre>
              <price>$12</price>
           </Book>
           <Book id="bk105">
              <author>Corets, Eva</author>
              <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
              <genre>Fiction</genre>
              <price>5.95</price>
           </Book>
        </Books>
```

Expected output XML:

```
   <Books>
           <Book id="bk101">
              <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
              <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
              <genre>Computer</genre>
              <price>44.95</price>
              <groupSeqId>1</groupSeqId>
           </Book>
           <Book id="bk102">
              <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
              <title>Midnight Rain</title>
              <genre>Fantasy</genre>
              <price>$5.95</price>
              <groupSeqId>1</groupSeqId>
           </Book>
           <Book id="bk104">
              <author>Corets, Eva</author>
              <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
              <genre>Fantasy</genre>
              <price>$12</price>
              <groupSeqId>2</groupSeqId>
           </Book>
           <Book id="bk103">
              <author>Corets, Eva</author>
              <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
              <genre>Fiction</genre>
              <price>5.95</price>
              <groupSeqId>1</groupSeqId>
           </Book>
           <Book id="bk105">
              <author>Corets, Eva</author>
              <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
              <genre>Fiction</genre>
              <price>5.95</price>
              <groupSeqId>2</groupSeqId>
           </Book>
        </Books>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)?

Comment: Hello Michael, I did see examples on Muenchian grouping but can I just sort without grouping it by a node? Also I am not sure on how to reset the sequence when the key changes.

Comment: Yes, you can sort. But you cannot number each group without grouping.

Comment: Thanks Michael, How to number within a group in case I group it.

Comment: You can simply use position(). Why don't you post the XSLT to make it easier for us?

Comment: Thanks Michael! I did attach the XSLT and it is working as expected.